# Get Browser's Download Directory Path with Firebreath?

Tags: firebreath

I am working on a browser plugin using Firebreath (so far loving it) and I need my plugin to be able to save a file to the user's computer.  I want the file to be saved to the browser's download directory (as set in the browser's preferences).  Is there a way to get that path?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Not using FireBreath / NPAPI.  NPAPI plugins do not know anything about the web browser, preference, etc.